# How to migrate exoplayer download keys

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3, exoplayer-media-item

Please help me. How to migrate exoplayer download manager data? I want to change download and cache keys.
I use media3 lib, don`t see the api for this in SimpleCache and DownloadManager.

If you have any solution, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can check `CacheKeyFactory` interface.
Provide your own `CacheKeyFactory` while creating `CacheDataSource`

```
CacheDataSource.Factory()
  .setCacheKeyFactory(CustomCacheKeyFactory())
  .build()
```

Comment: Sorry, but you don't understand my question. I need to migrate existing data. When i start the app, i want to change the keys. if i set setCacheKeyFactory the key comes new only for new cache data.